# Помогите решить проблему в Dev-C++ при роботе с библиотекой graphics.h

Tags: c++, devc++

При попытке запустить графическое окно:

```
#include <graphics.h>
int main()
{
    initwindow(500,500);
    
    getch();
    closegraph();   
}
```

программа выдает ошибку

```
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = main.o
LINKOBJ  = main.o
LIBS     = -L"D:/c++/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"D:/c++/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc -lbgi -lgdi32 -luser32
INCS     = -I"D:/c++/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"D:/c++/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"D:/c++/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"D:/c++/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"D:/c++/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"D:/c++/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"D:/c++/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"
BIN      = Project1.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) 
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) 
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Очевидно, надо озаботиться раздобыванием библиотеки bgi.

Comment: Вас в институте заставляют пользоваться `graphics.h`? Хорошо бы перейти на что-то менее древнее.

Comment: Поищите *BGI library implementation for Microsoft(R) Windows(TM) Copyright (C) 2006  Daniil G. Guitelson*... А, вот же она — https://github.com/daniilguit/openbgi